# Different programs in the same Xcode C++ project

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, xcode, development

I am trying to use XCode as my training environment for simple C++ programs. If I create a new project, I can successfully complete everything (compile, run) but If I add one more file, it can't compile as a separate one. That means that I need to have a main2() and a main3() etc. because having 2 files with two main() in the same folder lead to an error.

In simple words, I want to write code for 30 C++ examples, each one in its own .cpp file and compile every one of them separately and not as a whole project (all files together that If there are two functions of the same name, it will crash).

Comment: You would need to create separate target for each file. Here's more info on Apple Pages: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeBuild.html

Comment: I don't believe it would do because I need to setup a new schema for each file. We're talking about helloworld.cpp, factorial.cpp etc. - totally different programs from a book.

Comment: Uh, You have to wait a bit until I get more screenshots. You have to make separate targets in order to be able to compile separate programs.

Comment: I don't want to compile 30 programs each time I make a letter change in one of them. In case that XCode supports this type of use.

Comment: See my answer. You'll compile only one file, just change the target You'd like to compile.

Comment: I can't create new targets because when I am trying to create one, only the first one appears to be selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21408/discussion-between-mateusz-szlosek-and-robdel).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to compile multiple separate files (separate binaries as a result) You would need to create separate targets for every file.

To add new target please choose: **File** -> **New** -> **Target..**, select for example **Command Line Tool**. Make sure it's properly added to Your project. Here's example:
[image]

My `main.cpp` is added to target `multiple_targets` like this:
[image]

My `main-kopia.cpp` file is added to `target2` like this:
[image]

to be sure check the build phases for every target, here's example of my `target2` Build Phase:
[image]

With this I am able to compile both `main.cpp` and `main-kopia.cpp`. Notice that they both have `main()` inside them.

Comment: not much flexible, but at least works.

Comment: Wasn't the question really about compiling the files separately? With this, even when I create different targets. When I hit build only the first default main.cpp gets called.

Comment: I got it. Just one detail is missing here. While building we need to toggle the active scheme next to run and stop buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me hard time too. To fix this I had to make sure that the file I intend to compile is the only one that appears in the 'Build Phases' section.